# How do I compile an apache air app under linux?

Tags: linux, apache-flex, air, ubuntu-16.04, fdt

I am trying to use FDT to compile and run a simple application. I've tried following the tutorial at:

http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/Installing_and_Running_FDT

but it is pretty thin on details.

Basically, I downloaded and installed the FDT Free tarball for 64bit linux from http://fdt.powerflasher.com/buy-download/

It complained about not having a Flex SDK, so I downloaded the all platforms package for Adobe Flex 4.6 SDK from http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html

I then created a sample app trying to follow the instructions at: http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/Flex_/_Air_Tutorial#Creating_Our_Project

Changing nothing in the sample app, I clicked on `SampleApp.mxml` and selected Run As FDT AIR Application.

All I got for my trouble was a

```
/home/peter/opt/flex_sdk_4.6/bin/adl: 1: /home/peter/opt/flex_sdk_4.6/bin/adl: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

The only parentheses in the SampleApp that I can find are in a comment on line 5.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

I've also found some instructions for installing the Apache Flex SDK at http://flex.apache.org/installer.html
But those instructions don't work both the download links that seemed to apply were broken:

http://apache.mirror.colo-serv.net/flex/installer/3.2/binaries/apache-flex-sdk-installer-3.2.0-bin.deb

https://builds.apache.org/job/flex-sdk_release/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/out/apache-flex-sdk-4.12.0-bin.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Adobe AIR isn't supported on linux.
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2249067

> 2. Re: Installing AIR on Ubuntu 16  ridhijain Adobe Employee ridhijain Employee Jun 12, 2017 3:01 AM (in response to vurkkosturiumGajo) Hi,
>      Adobe AIR is no more supported on Linux platforms. Please see Tech
>      specs and system requirements | Adobe AIR  for supported platforms.
>      The last Adobe AIR version supported on Linux was version 2.6.  This
>      is available for download from the AIR Archive page.   Thanks!

This guy did it with wine:
http://jcward.com/Setup+AIR+3.9+SDK+On+Ubuntu+12.04

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Why would FDT be supported on linux if it required an SDK that wasn't supported on linux?

Comment: @spierepf IIRC AIR used to be supported, so that would give you the 'why'.  But I don't think this answer explains the behavior you're seeing:  ADL is running but complaining about a syntax error, not refusing to run at all.

Comment: @Brian I was under the impression that Apache was picking up Adobe's slack with respect to this stuff.

Comment: @spierepf Apache makes the Flex SDK > 4.6 , Adobe makes the AIR SDK (All Versions) and Flex SDK < 4.7